# How to Connect the Button and a Text Area from different Classes in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

I want to make a window that when you press the buttons it will show the phrase "I Love You" in different language in the text area. I Just don't know how to connect the text area in the buttons. I have three classes. I tried many ways I could think and I also search the things related to this but I can't find any useful

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run()   {
                new MainFrame();
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame  {
            
    private ToolBar Tulbar = new ToolBar();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    
    public MainFrame() {
        super("This window loves you");
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(Tulbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class ToolBar extends JPanel{

    private JButton Button1 = new JButton("Korean");
    private JButton Button2 = new JButton("Japanese");
    private JButton Button3 = new JButton("French");
    private JButton Button4 = new JButton("Italian");
    private JButton Button5 = new JButton("English");
    private JButton Button6 = new JButton("Tagalog");
    
    public ToolBar() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        //added buttons

        add(Button1);
        add(Button2);
        add(Button3);
        add(Button4);
        add(Button5);
        add(Button6);
        
    }
    
    public ToolBar(JTextArea frame) {
        
        Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("Saranghae");
            }
            
        });
        

        Button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("Aishiteru");
            }
            
        });
        
        Button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("Je t\'aime");
            }
            
        });

        Button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("Ti\'amo");
            }
            
        });

        Button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("I Love You");
            }
            
        });

        Button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.append("Mahal Kita");
            }
            
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The code adds 2 action listeners to `Button4` but none to `Button6`. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) `public class ToolBar extends JPanel{` Use a `JToolBar`. It's made for this! 4) `private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); .. setSize(600,600);` better `private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(r,c); .. pack();`, where `r` is the number of rows and `c` the number of columns that would be optimal. ..

Comment: .. The call to `pack()` then makes the GUI the size it needs to be in order to display the components and the (PLAF/OS specific) window decorations. 5) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Tip for shortening: 2 buttons, rather than 6. 6) `public class MainFrame extends JFrame  {` Don't extend `JFrame` either, just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `Button1.addActionListener` in `public ToolBar(JTextArea frame)` constructor, you should invoke this constructor to invoke the code in it. But instead you are invoking `public ToolBar()` constructor.

To fix this instead of:

```
    private ToolBar Tulbar = new ToolBar();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
```

you should write:

```
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    private ToolBar Tulbar = new ToolBar(textArea);
```

and in `ToolBar`  fix the constructors, instead of:

```
    public ToolBar() {
       // ... STUFF 1 ...
    }
    
    public ToolBar(JTextArea frame) {
        // ... STUFF 2 ...
    }
```

you should write:

```
    public ToolBar(JTextArea frame) {
        // ... STUFF 1 ...
        // ... STUFF 2 ...
    }
```

or

```
    public ToolBar() {
       // ... STUFF 1 ...
    }
    
    public ToolBar(JTextArea frame) {
        this();
        // ... STUFF 2 ...
    }
```

Please learn [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and use it all the time. You probably don't think it's important, but I promise it will save you from making stupid mistakes, and will save your time fixing them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will learn Java Naming conventions.